# Panchratnam phase observation in interference of laser light

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-optics

I am working on anisotropy measurement in crystals using Pockel cell crystal and [image: Setup for interfering light coming out from crystal and the light from laser]

I am confused about how can I use the interference pattern which I got to study about the Berry-Panchratnam phase using some image processing technique?

Comment: As far as I remember, you need at least three polarizer to get a geometric phase. Did you try to read the original paper, reference in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_phase